# PyQt5 cannot import name 'QApplication'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying convert my code from PyQt4 to PyQt5 but I am getting errors.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap
desktop = QApplication.desktop()
QPixmap.grabWindow(desktop.screen().winId()).save("screen.png", "PNG")


3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Projects\name.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap
ImportError: cannot import name 'QApplication'
```

Comment: Going over http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html might help...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`QApplication` is located in `PyQt5.QtWidgets` module. So your import statement should be:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

Answer (score 27):

[QApplication](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qapplication.html) is in PyQt5.QtWidgets.

So it should be

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

Comment: Upvoting not because it solved my problem, but because a pretty much identical and later answer got upvotes.